# Convert C++ standard containers into JSON

Tags: c++, serialization, stl, rapidjson

I'm using RapidJSON to output my objects as JSON strings. It's rather intuitive to use it with my custom classes, but I'm wondering is there built-in way to convert STL containers to JSON. It seems pretty straightforward to implement it for specialized `map`, `pair` and `vector` objects, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Unfortunately I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

If there is no built in method/operator for this, what is the preferred way? I thought creating boxing classes with added `toJSON` methods or implementing `ostream& operator<<`s for the specialized containers.

Comment: There is no built in way to convert the container content into JSON. Standard C++ Library is oblivious of JSON.

Comment: I meant built into the RapidJSON. Like an operator (`writer << map`) or parsing constructor, eg. `Document d(map)` where type of map is `map<string,vector<int>>` or something.  An abstract class will be good enough for me.

Comment: Have you looked at: [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) It requires a simple declaration per type and STL containers are automatically supported. [Example](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example2.md) Note: I wrote it.

Comment: Looks promising. Currently I'm working with a helper class that uses RapidJSON but I'm struggling with it. I think I will try your lib. Do you have any benchmark for speed/memory?